# How to change ContentURI in Weblogic Portlet?

Tags: jsp, struts, weblogic, portlet

I am developing an application which uses Weblogic portlets and Struts. All I need to do is to load different jsp's in the same portlet based on the web browser that client is using.

For eg: If I have a portlet called home.portlet. If the user is using IE it should display IE.jsp in the home.portlet, if he is using firefox I should display firefox.jsp in home.portlet.

This is what I have in home.portlet:

```
<netuix:content>
        <netuix:jspContent contentUri="IE.jsp"/>
    </netuix:content>


 //in struts config file
 <forward name="firefox" path="/firefox.jsp>
```

This is what I did to achieve it- In homeAction.java:

```
if(firefox)
return mapping.findForward("firefox");
```

So even if the user is using firefox it is displaying IE.jsp.
How can we change the jsp content in the portlet from the Struts Action Class so that I can check the kind of the browser the user is using and display the page accordingly??

All help and suggestions appreciated.

Thanks,

-Sai

Comment: Browser sniffing considered harmful. What happens if someone uses Chrome, Safari, Opera, ...?

Comment: @ninjalj: I mentioned an example. Thats not all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My portlets wern't configured for struts. I changed that now, and its working fine.

EG:

```
<netuix:strutsContent action="getStudentList" module = "people/students"
  refreshAction = "getStudentList" reqestAttrpersistence="none"/>
```

And then in the action class I am checking for the browser and displaying the appropriate jsp

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check for browser in your homeAction.java and do the forward based on that.

Try this to check browser version in your action.

```
public void checkBrowserType (HttpServletRequest req)
{
   String s = req.getHeader("user-agent");
   if (s == null)
      return;
   if (s.indexOf("MSIE") > -1)
      System.out.println("using Internet Explorer");
   else if (s.indexOf("Netscape") > -1)
      System.out.println("using Netscape");
   // etc ...   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had problem with the portlets. I already have the code to check the useragent. I figured it out. I a kind of dumb. My portlets wasnt configured for struts. I changed that now, and its working fine. Thanks

Comment: @Sai - if your question is answered then do accept the answer to close the question